# How to move category filters in layered navigation after the attribute filters

Tags: category, layered-navigation

Is there any method by which we can move the category filters after the attribute filters in layered navigation using layout config files

Searching i reached this question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423859/how-to-change-category-filter-position-in-magento-layer-navigation)

But i want to know whether it is possible with layout xml files OR
Alter the order of occurrence in `layer\view.phtml` ( is this not at all a good idea?)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the best way to achieve this would be to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View` in a custom module and then change the function `getFilters` so that it looks something like the following:

```
public function getFilters()
{
    $filters = array();
    $filterableAttributes = $this->_getFilterableAttributes();
    foreach ($filterableAttributes as $attribute) {
        $filters[] = $this->getChild($attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_filter');
    }

    if ($categoryFilter = $this->_getCategoryFilter()) {
        $filters[] = $categoryFilter;
    }

    return $filters;
}
```

Comment: did same thing only, but just to alter the order of appearance we need to write code in custom module. If would have been much easier if possible with layout xml files.

Comment: I dont think you can as it treats all filters as the same even if they are categories or product attributes. one other option would be to do an array sort in the template but I would suggest the rewrite would be better.