# How to change category location block in magento 1.8?

Tags: magento-1.8, category, layout, blocks

Is it possible to exchange positions of the list of categories and the price filter in the left sidebar:

[image]

Comment: please ask clearly what you want to do

Comment: i have a category list in a left sidebar. Below that i have price filter. 
It should swap them

Comment: you have to swap those two position category and price ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check given below URLs to solve your problem.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423859/how-to-change-category-filter-position-in-magento-layer-navigation
2. [How to move category filters in layered navigation after the attribute filters](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12683/how-to-move-category-filters-in-layered-navigation-after-the-attribute-filters)

Answer (score 0):

Goto

`app/design/frontend/yourPackage/Yourtheme/template/catalog/navigation/left.php`

Here you find `subcategory` `foreach` loop

`foreach ($_categories as $_category):`

change this `foreach` loop position as your requirement and your job is done.